# Receive input in file format from swagger form (Django)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-spectacular

```
# model
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, CommonModel):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    certification_profile = models.URLField(null=True)
 
    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "phone"



# view
class UserCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):

serializer_class = UserCreateSerializer
parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)



# serializer
class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    certification_profile = serializers.FileField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = (
            'phone',
            'nickname',
            'certification_profile',
        )


    def create(self, validated_data):
        certification_profile = validated_data.pop('certification_profile', None)
        user = get_user_model().objects.create(**validated_data)
        if certification_profile is not None:
            image_uuid = str(uuid4())
            ## upload file
            ...
            user.certification_profile = certification_profile_url
            user.save()

        self._create_interests(interests, user)
        return user
```

The certification_profile column of the User model is URLfield.

I would like to receive certification_profile in the form of a file and save it in the form of a url later.

So, I specified certification_profile = serializers.FileField(required=False) in UserCreateSerializer.

However, as shown in the picture below, the swagger form continues to receive string input.

[image]

How can I receive input in the form of a file in swagger form?

thanks for reading the long post!

Comment: Add """SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'COMPONENT_SPLIT_REQUEST': True,
}""" to settings.py was fixed it.